# Hyperlinks in html5 not opening like expected

Tags: html, href

Could someone please help me with `href` link.

When I add a `href` link in the `html` editor it doesn't open alone but it follows my website link.

Example: I want to open a www.google.com when I add this it appears like

```
www.mysite.com/www.google.com
```

How can I fix this problem please?

Comment: also post your code sample for better understanding

Comment: put your code segment,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your code, but try this:

```
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com">I'm a link!</a>
```

It's the default `href`

EDIT:

Maybe if you have the `href` like this: (whitout the "http")

```
<a href="www.yoursite.com">I'm a link!</a>
```

The web navigator think that it's something like this:

```
<a href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
```

Comment: Sorry if I have bad english :/ English is not my first language

Comment: Thank you very much it worked well just by adding https :)

Comment: Next time @MohammedSaad paste your code, will be easy to find the problem